# Rendering Issue - Tracked Video & 3D Object Composite

Tags: rendering, camera, tracking, layers

When I render the scene, only the tracked video appears; the 3D objects do not render. However, the objects appear if I set my active view to rendered (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>). "Restrict Rendering" is inactive.

After rendering, this message appears:

> No Layers in Render Result

Answer (score 1):

Might be an obvious one, but check your render layer setup and which layers your objects are on... 
[image]

Also check your compositing node setup after rendering an image. I've had problems in the past when I accidentally moved objects to layers that were selected as a mask layer or Excluded layer.